# How should I implement a pure virtual method with derived type as parameter?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance

I am making a program in C++, I come from Java and I am having some troubles.
I would like to have a base abstract class (a java interface) which defines some methods that derived classes have to implement. This methods can have the derived types as parameters, but here I found a problem. If I define them with base class as parameters in the base class, the compiler doesn't see the re-definitions with derived types as an override and the derived classes are still pure virtual. 
What's the correct way to resolve this situation? 
Thanks!

Comment: This shouldn't work in Java, either. Contravariance requires having the derived type in the base class signature and base type in the derived class signature.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to write something like this:

```
template<class T>
class Interface {
  virtual void Method(T i) = 0;
};

class Implement : public Interface<Implement> {
  virtual void Method(Implement i) override {

  }
};
```

This is called [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

What you should do here is create a function in the derived class which takes the base class as parameter. You can use `dynamic_cast` to make sure that the runtime type is indeed the derived class (and throw an exception otherwise). As chris mentioned in his comment, Contravariance is "hard".

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void fn(const Base &base)=0;
}
class Derived:public Base
{
     void fn(const Base &base)
     {
         const Derived *derived=dynamic_cast<const Derived *>(&base);
         if(derived!=nullptr)
         {//code for derived..
         }

     }
}
```

If you really must have what you asked for, you should go for [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). I suspect you really don't need to. If you really need it, Adrian's answer is what you're looking for.

Keep in mind that if you opt for CRTP, you would lose out on some of the benefits of inheritance. You wouldn't, for instance, be able to create a list of Base class pointers (`vector <Base *>`). You'd need to pick your derived class whenever you use your Base class (`Base<Derived>`), which may defeat the purpose.

Comment: I would flag this in code reviews It violates the Liskov principle because I cannot use a Derived object everywhere a Base object is expected.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do would not work in Java either. In Java, the return type can be covariant, but not the method's arguments. If you consider the Liskov principle, that actually makes sense: If you narrow the contract for derived classes, you will not be able to substitute a base object with a derived object.

A solution probably needs to be on the design level. Just guessing, but this kind of problem relates to situations where you want a dispatch on the class, and on the argument type. If that is the case, take a look at [Visitor pattern.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)